# Getting http 400 bad request only if I use a relative address on my endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm getting a:

> http 400 bad request

error only if I use a relative address on my endpoint.

If I remove "basic" from the address I can view the WSDL definition without any problem:

```
http://localhost:8001/Test/
```

But as soon as I add "basic" and open up a browser and type in:

```
http://localhost:8001/Test/basic
```

i get the error.

Here's my config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="HostConsole.ContactService" 
               behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" >
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8001/Test/"/>
          </baseAddresses>          
        </host>
        <endpoint address="basic" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  contract="HostConsole.IContactService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

ServiceHost:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ContactService));

try {
    host.Open();

    foreach (ServiceEndpoint se in host.Description.Endpoints) {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "Address: {0}",
            se.Address.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Enter to close");
    Console.ReadLine();

    host.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    host.Abort();
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The address field you have with "basic" in it comes after the full service URL.  I don't see a separate service activation in here or the name of your .svc file, but it would be something like 
`http://localhost:8001/Test/YourService.svc/basic` .

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not hosting in IIS so I don't have a *.svc file.